# Configuring many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Code First when both entities reside in different SQL Server Databases.

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I'm relatively new to software development and i'm currently finishing up a project that I'm hoping to show at future job interviews. In this project, using code-first I want to set up a many-to-many relationship between an ApplicationUser and a domain Entity and have the resulting associative table persist other information that pertains to this association. The idea is that a user would be able to like many images and an image would be able to have many users like it. The problem that I've come across is that the Identity Database and the domain database are not the same. So my questions are:

1) How would I be able to create the many-to-many association between the ApplicationUsers and the Photos if both Entities are persisted in different SQL Server Databases?

2) How could I add a field to store extra information (a bool to account for whether the user liked the image or not) in that resulting associative table?

Thanks in advance for the answers, I'm usually able to find answers on my own but this one seems to be a little off the beaten track.

Comment: there is no way to do this automatically with EF, since the entities reside in different contexts and noone can ensure referential integrity. the only possibility I could think of is creating a link table in one of the databases consisting the corresponding PK's of both entities, you'd have to deal with that manually though, or save the relationship in another form somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ApplicationUser` table in the domain database and have your image/user junction table reference that.  Every time a user logs into your application, insert/update that user record with the relevant information from your identity database.  If your identity database serves only the single application, you can combine the two databases.

Comment: Thanks, Moho! That makes sense.